# Combine each element with all the others in sublists

Tags: combinatorics, list-manipulation

Suppose that I have a list of numbers

```
list = {{{1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}}, {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, -1}}}
```

I would like to Join each element of the first sublist with each element of the second list. In principle I would like to do it recursively, so the list might have also multiple sublists. The final result should be

```
final = {
{{1,0,-1, 0, 1}, {1,0,-1, 1, -1}, {1,0,-1, -1, 0}, {1,0,1, 1, 0}, {1,0,1, -1, 1}, {1,0,1, 0, -1}}, (*first union*)
{{-1, 1,-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1,-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1,-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1,1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1,1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1,1, 0, -1}},  (*second union*)
{{0, -1,-1, 0, 1}, {0, -1,-1, 1, -1}, {0, -1,-1, -1, 0}, {0, -1,1, 1, 0}, {0, -1,1, -1, 1}, {0, -1,1, 0, -1}}  (*third union*)
}
```

In case I had three sublist, I need to create all possible combination of these final result (which can be flattened) with the element of the third sublist. So I was thinking of sum recursive solution that applies to each pair of the array.

What is the correct way of doing it in Mathematica?

EDIT with example:

Just to give you a case with three vectors:
`list ={{{1}},{{1,0},{-1,1},{0,-1}},{{-1,0,1},{-1,1,-1},{-1,-1,0},{1,1,0},{1,-1,1},{1,0,-1}}}`,

I made a loop like:

```
temp={};
Do[
temp=AppendTo[temp,Join[list[[1,i]],list[[2,j]],list[[3,k]]]];
,{i,1,Length[list[[1]]]},{j,1,Length[list[[2]]]},{k,1,Length[list[[3]]]}]
```

and it does the job, but of course, I could have a list with more than three sublists, and for sure there is a better way than a Do loop. But now it is clear what I want, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the desired ouput like so:

```
Join@Outer[Join, list[[1]], list[[2]], 1]
```

and check

```
final - Join@Outer[Join, list[[1]], list[[2]], 1]
```

> [image: test]

Comment: Perfect, I can use your function `Join@Outer[Join, Evaluate @@ list, 1]` for a generic long list and it works. I then flatten as much time as I need. Thanks!

Comment: @AlessandroMininno hi. Yes, indeed this is the idea. You can pass as many lists as you want. You might want to have a look at [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html), but it seems you got the general picture